# Property '' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context, react-typescript

I am trying to set up a context hook to be used for my Login page. I am using Typescript. I started the context hook, but am running into problems with declaration of types. When I try using setUser this is the error that pops up: **Property 'setUser' does not exist on type '{}'.**

Here is my context hook so far.

```
import { createContext, ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from "react"

interface Props {
    children?: ReactNode
}


export const UserContext = createContext({})

export function UserContextProvider({children}: Props) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And here is my Login code.

```
import { Link, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
import axios from 'axios'
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext"


const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false)
  **const {setUser} = useContext(UserContext)**

  async function handleLogin(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      const userInfo = await axios.post('/auth/login', {email, password})
      setUser(userInfo)
      alert('Login')
      setRedirect(true)
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Login failed')
    }
  }

  if(redirect){
    return <Navigate to={'/'} />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <input type="email" placeholder="your@email.com" 
          value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
          <input type="password" placeholder="password" 
          value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
          <button>Login</button>
          <div>
            Don't have an account?
            <Link to={"/auth/register"}> Sign Up</Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: The type has to be inferred from `createContext({})`, because you never bothered to supply one. That value indeed has no `setUser` (or any other) property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a type for your `UserContext` variable. Because you've given it an argument of `{}` in `createContext`, typescript assumes that the context has a type of `React.Context<{}>`. Hence, when you try to use the context object, you get back an `{}`, an empty object, which has no user-defined properties.

To start, I'll define a new interface, but you can type it however you want.

```js
interface IUserContext {
  user: any;
  setUser: any; //set your definitions here (please don't use `any`)
}
```

To declare the type of `UserContext`, you can:

1. Provide a default value that matches the type

   ```js
   export const UserContext = createContext<IUserContext>("<defaultValueHere>");
   ```
2. Set the default context value as an empty object/null

   ```js
   export const UserContext = createContext<IUserContext|{}>({});
   export const UserContext = createContext<IUserContext|null>(null);
   ```
3. Type-cast an empty object (less type-safe)

   ```js
   export const UserContext = createContext<IUserContext>({} as IUserContext);
   ```
4. Non-null assertion (less type-safe)

   ```js
   export const UserContext = createContext<IUserContext>(null!);
   ```

Do note that for some of these, you'll need to write null checks later. See [here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/) for more information.